# Area relationship for projections of a plane region

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

I saw the following problem in a multivariable calculus problem set but no solutions were included. I find the problem interesting and I would like to see both a calculus solution and a non-calculus solution (a geometric one) if possible.

Consider a plane region $S$  in $R^3$. Let the area of the projections of $S$ onto the planes $x=0$,$y=0$,$z=0$ be $a_1$,$a_2$,$a_3$ respectively, and let the area of $S$ be $a$. Show that $a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2=a^2$.

Note: a plane region is a region embedded in a plane.

Answer (score 1):

Projection from one plane onto another multiplies areas by $\cos\theta$ if the angle between the planes is $\theta$.  If $\bf n$ is the unit normal to the plane $P$ containing $S$, the cosines of the angles between $P$ and the planes $x=0$, $y=0$ and $z=0$ are $|{\bf n} \cdot {\bf i}| = |n_1|$, $|{\bf n} \cdot {\bf j}| =|n_2|$ and $|{\bf n} \cdot {\bf k}| =|n_3|$ respectively.  So we have
$$ a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 = a^2 (n_1^2 + n_2^2 + n_3^2) = a^2$$

Comment: How do you get that $n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2=1$?

Comment: Look up direction cosines. sum of squares =1. Special case of 2 dimensions reduces to $\sin^2(-) + \cos^2(-) = 1 $

Comment: Ahh I see. Beautiful solution!

Answer (score 0):

From a geometric perspective, this seems to be an extension of the Pythagorean theorem. Consider a simpler situation, where $T$ is a line segment in $\mathbb{R}^2$. If you let the length of $T$ be $b$, and the lengths of the projections onto $x=0$ and $y=0$ be $b_1$ and $b_2$, then it should be clear that $b_1^2+b_2^2=b^2$.

Furthermore, if $R$ is a line segment in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with length $c$ and plane projections with lengths $c_1, c_2,$ and $c_3$, then $c_1^2+c_2^2+c_3^2=c^2$.

I think it seems clear that the same should hold true for plane regions and area, but I don't have the experience with geometry to prove it rigorously. I imagine it would be analagous to the situation with the Pythagorean Theorem in 3 dimensions: first consider the case when the plane containing $S$ is perpendicular to one of the planes, say $z=0$. Then show that $a_1^2+a_2^2=a^2$ in that case. Then, for the general case, consider the planes $z=0$, $y=mx$, and $y=\frac{x}{-m}$ with $m$ chosen so that $y=\frac{x}{-m}$ is perpendicular to the plane containing $S$. Then the first part shows that the projection onto $y=mx$ has area $\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}$ and that $\left(\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}\right)^2+a_3^2=a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2=a^2$