# Area of a figure in terms of height and width

Tags: geometry, area

Attempting to give a thorough geometric answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1050256/area-relationship-for-projections-of-a-plane-region/)
made me wonder:

Can the area of any two-dimensional figure be expressed as a scaled product of its height and width? That is, for an arbitrary two-dimensional shape with height $h$, width $w$, and area $a$, is there some $c\in\mathbb{R}$ so that $a=chw$? I don't need a general formula, because of course $c$ would be different for different shapes, or even rotations, but is it guaranteed to exist?

It seems like it should, but I can't figure out how to go about proving it.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "shape". If you allow any subset of the plane then for certain shapes there isn't even a defined area. But assuming there is an area a and it has a width and height, we can always set $c=\frac{a}{hw}$.

Comment: @jef I am assuming that the shape has a defined area. It looks like I was over-thinking the problem and overlooking the obvious solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You admit that $c$ will vary from one shape to another.  What you can do is come up with a $c$ for any measurable shape.  All shapes that are in a similarity class and the same orientation will have the same $c$, and in fact the same ratio of width to height.  So you can even come up with a formula $A=c'h^2$, as the area will scale by the square of any linear dimension.

Comment: The shape also needs to be bounded so that the width and height are finite.